# How to get input value one by one using setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here, I want to create a something like slideshow concept which get the value one by one using setInterval function.I have just tried to implement based logically, but it not working as expected,just got error output.So how to repair and improve my code below?

jQuery

```
  setInterval(function() { 
     var getValue = $('#slideShow').find('input:first').val()
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideShow');
     alert(getValue);
},  3000);
```

html

```
<div id="slideShow">
    <input type="hidden" value="one"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="two"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="three"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: `.val()` returns a value, a string, it can't be chained with  `fadeOut` etc

Comment: Set up jsfiddle/demo. And describe what errors you have got

Comment: val() returns a value(string ) not object so you can chan like that

Comment: hmm..i got "TypeError: $(...).find(...).val(...).fadeOut is not a function"

Comment: you are getting error fadeout() not a function because `val()` doesn't have fadeout method

Comment: Ok,I have the correct answer below :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't chain the `.fadeOut()` method after the `.val()` method like that.

The `.val()` method doesn't return the jQuery object, it either [returns a string/number/array](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

The `.fadeOut()` method expected a jQuery object, which is why you were receiving an error.

You could use:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/h1m38f48/)

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var getValue = $('#slideShow').find('input:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideShow');

    alert(getValue.val());
},  3000);
```